Why is it necessary the inflaton field?
The Friedmann equations read $(+---)$:
$$\frac{\dot{a}^2+kc^2}{a^2} = \frac{8\pi G\rho + \Lambda c^2}{3}$$
$$3\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = \Lambda c^2 - 4\pi G \left(\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}\right)$$
$$\dot{\rho} = -3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\left(\rho + \frac{p}{c^2}\right)$$
We thus have for $\rho \gg \Lambda c^2$ and $kc^2/a^2$ negligible compared to $\rho$:
$$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho$$
$$\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = - \frac{4\pi G}{3} \left(\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}\right)$$
$$\dot{\rho} = -3H\left(\rho + \frac{p}{c^2}\right)$$
With $H=\dot{a}/a$. Given $p=w\rho c^2$ and $w=0$ for dust and $w=1/3$ for radiation, then we get something that closely acts like an inflation for $\rho \gg 0$.
Why would we ever need another field to explain this growth? The expansion rate $H$ is positive and huge and its acceleration is $\ddot{a}/a < 0$ and quickly slowing down. Shouldn't an insurmountable energy density at $t=0$ be enough to trigger such an inflationary expansion?

What does $\gg0$ mean?

Inflation is not simply a stage when $\rho$ was very large. To understand what is needed, you should consider the causal structure of spacetime.
Let us take the flat FRLW metric,
\begin{equation*}
ds^2=dt^2-a^2(t) d\vec{x}^2
\end{equation*}
The time $t$ is a nice time that is equal to the proper time for $\vec{x}=\operatorname{const}$ observers (which are geodesic). However it is useful to consider a different time - the conformal time $\eta$ such that $d\eta=dt / a(t)$. Then the metric takes the form,
\begin{equation*}
ds^2=a^2(\eta)\Big(d\eta^2-d\vec{x}^2\Big)
\end{equation*}
Notice that the metric becomes proportional to the Minkowski metric. So the factor $a^2(\eta)$ becomes irrelevant if you restrict your attention to $ds^2=0$ trajectories. In these coordinates, light moves along $\Delta\eta=|\Delta\vec{x}|$ lines. You can draw spacetime diagrams just like in the Minkowski spacetime - with light moving along diagonal lines.
Now, if you consider $w=\frac{p}{\rho}=\operatorname{const}$ spacetimes, an important difference can be noticed for cases $w>-1/3$ (with $\ddot{a}<0$) and $w<-1/3$ (with $\ddot{a}>0$)
For $w>-1/3$ e.g. for the radiation dominated universe with $w=+1/3$ (like at very early times) the spacetime diagram is

The Big Bang singularity cuts off the spacetime at finite $\eta$ in the past. Then the light travelled a finite distance since the beginning of the universe - we have a cosmological horizon. So our observable universe is finite.
However, a problem appears. You can see that events $A$ and $B$ in the very early universe had even smaller horizon. So what we see at large distances are regions that in that early times were causally disconnected from each other - no signal could reach $B$ from $A$ since the beginning of the universe. What is surprising is that, nevertheless, we see very homogeneous early universe.
For $w<-1/3$ the spacetime diagram looks completely different.

Now, such spacetime for $w>-1$ still has a Big Bang singularity at finite $t$ in the past. However in terms of conformal time such singularity is at infinite negative $\eta$ because of that all the events in such spacetime have common past. Instead, the asymptotic future lies at finite $\eta$ and another sort of horizon appears - from certain moment it becomes impossible to send a signal from $A$ to $B$ (because the light can't catch up with the accelerating expansion)
If we combine this spacetime by assuming that at late times we have $w>-1/3$ but at earlier times we have $w<-1/3$ (the inflationary stage) we get

Now we can explain the homogeneous early universe because instead of "light couldn't travel from $A$ to $B$ since the beginning of the universe" it becomes "light couldn't travel from $A$ to $B$ since the end of inflation". But even if $A$ was very far from $B$ they still had common past. As they are not independent, we can explain why the early universe were so homogeneous.
We need to produce the sufficiently long early stage with $w<-1/3$ but that could transfer into a hot universe filled with radiation that would evolve into the observed one. This is most easily done with the scalar field slowly rolling in a shallow potential. When it reaches the minimum of the potential the energy in this field can be turned into a very hot gas of particles. Hence, the inflaton idea.
In fact, very fast accelerated expansion means that all our observable universe was born from the extremely tiny region. We can neglect any particle-like matter that was in such region then and assume that it was vacuum with homogeneous inflationary field distribution. The quantum fields evolving in such spacetime would produce small inhomogeneities with such spectrum that is in a very good agreement with the observed CMB temperature fluctuations.

Damn dude such a good answer. Thanks a million for the effort you put in!
